How can I replicate transactions one by one in mysql?
I have one source server and one replica server. And I set source_delay 30mins, replication is gtid based, mysql version is 8.0.24

If I accidentally drop table A, Can I apply transactions just right before the drop transaction??

What is the best solution when I accidentally drop table and I want to restore minimum data loss?


I tried restore table using replica's table which have data before 30 mins. So there is no data which is delayed.

You can use mysqlbinlog to examine the binary logs, to get the exact position where the DROP TABLE A event occurs.
Here's an example from my local instance, where I ran a drop table event.
$ mysqlbinlog -v -v binlog.000011 | egrep '^# at |DROP TABLE'
# at 4
# at 127
# at 158
# at 235
DROP TABLE `mytable` /* generated by server */

We see the event of the drop table is at position 235 in that binlog file.
Then on the replica, you can run replication until that position.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/start-replica.html says:

The UNTIL clause makes the replica start replication, then process transactions up to the point that you specify in the UNTIL clause, then stop again. The UNTIL clause can be used to make a replica proceed until just before the point where you want to skip a transaction that is unwanted, and then skip the transaction as described in Section 19.1.7.3, “Skipping Transactions”. To identify a transaction, you can use mysqlbinlog with the source's binary log or the replica's relay log, or use a SHOW BINLOG EVENTS statement.

START REPLICA UNTIL SOURCE_LOG_FILE='binlog.000011' SOURCE_LOG_POS=235;

The source log file name and position are just examples from my instance. Your instance will likely have different values.
As when learning any new procedure like this one, I suggest you practice it on a test instance before you attempt to do it with your important data.
